Need help with upgrading Magento Cloud version 2.4.3-p3 to 2.4.7
Can somene please help me with upgrading Magento Cloud version 2.4.3-p3 to 2.4.7.
I have tried these commands:
composer require "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage":">=2.4.3 <2.4.7" --no-update
composer update --with-all-dependencies --ignore-platform-reqs

Also, updated the PHP version to 8.3, but it's not working. Can someone please help?
After the upgrade, I get this error in CLI:


Could you provide a screenshot or any detailed information about what error you are facing while upgrading?

Hi @JigarKarangiya, I have added the screenshot and the details as well.

It doesn't seem your PHP version is upgraded to 8.3, can you please check and confirm with the command php -v, Adding a command in the answer section to upgrade Magento cloud version.

Hi, The PHP version is already 8.3, but still getting the error.

Step 1: Update your PHP version to 8.3
Confirm the PHP version using the below command :
php -v

Step 2 : Update Magento Meta Package
composer require-commerce "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage":">=2.4.3-p3 < 2.4.7" --ignore-platform-reqs

or
composer require-commerce "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage":">=2.4.6-p3 < 2.4.7" -W

Here, 2.4.6-p3 is your current version and  2.4.7 is the version you want to upgrade to.
Step 3: Run composer update
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs

Step 4:  Check the Magento version
php bin/magento --version

Step 5: Run all commands
php bin/magento s:up && php bin/magento s:d:c && php bin/magento s:s:d -f && php bin/magento c:f


Hi, The PHP version is already 8.3, but still getting the error.
